# Problems with deploying on AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, web, amazon-ec2

I tried to deploy for the first time a MERN app on the AWS EC2.

I completed this [article](https://medium.com/@rksmith369/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-app-on-aws-ec2-with-ssl-nginx-the-right-way-e76c1a8cd6c6)'s steps, except for installing the mongodb, because I used Ubuntu 20.04 instead of 16.04, I used the docs and it had worked.

In the end I opened the app.js from /server/dist with pm2 and I had got the status of working, but when I wanted to access the website, it said that the connection was refused.

This is my github [repository](https://github.com/MariusAtasiei/amazon-clone).

If you have time and experience with AWS EC2, please check it! I didn't find anything, why it wouldn't work.

UPDATE:

I tried to curl the localhost, and it returns the html page, so it works.
I checked the status of the nginx and it is running, but I think nginx is the problem.

I tried to set it up using this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04). And when I test the nginx I got an ok, but it still doesn't work.

This is what /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/amazon-clone contains:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www/your_domain/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; server_name;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        proxy_pass http://172.31.39.190:5000;
    }
```

}

Comment: It's hard for us to help you if you don't provide any info or tell us what you've tried, you better answer these questions yourself first: Does the app logs any unhandled error (which won't terminate Node process)? Can you access the app from the inside the EC2, ex: calling `curl -X GET http://localhost` from terminal? Can you access the app from the outside of the EC2 (via IP)? Have you checked your firewall or policy?...

Comment: Sorry!

I did a curl. The server is working apparently.
And when I checked the nginx status, it says that it works too.

So I searched another way to set the proxy. I used this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04).

And when I tested it. I got this answer:
`nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "server_name" directive in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/amazon-clone:5`
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: This is what I have in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/amazon-clone:
`server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/your_domain/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html; server_name;

location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
proxy__pass 172.31.39.190:5000;
}
}
`

Comment: on which port is your node.js server running ?

Comment: `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_redirect http://localhost:5000/ /;`

Comment: The Node Server is on 5000.

Comment: Done! It worked!! I had to add the proxy_redirect. Can you post that comment as an answer to badge it as the right answer.